# Listar dados de uma API no android

Tags: android, web-service, android-studio, listview

Olá, estou tentando listar dados de uma API web, como nunca listei dessa maneira estou encontrando problemas para entender a solução da listagem, a URl da API retorna alguns valores que quero lista-los na activity Main, porém ao entrar na linha com o seguinte trecho:

```
arrayList.add((Coins) lCoins);
```

gerando a seguinte exceção:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

Até esta linha `lCoins = new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Coins>>(){}.getType() );`os dados são recuperados perfeitamente, porém ao tentar jogar ela na lista para o usuário o erro é apresentado. Segue abaixo as classes em questão

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//ATRIBUTOS
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<Coins> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //********* CONFIGURANDO A LISTAGEM DAS MOEDAS **********/
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_coins);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CoinsAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //********* FIM CONFIGURANDO A LISTAGEM DAS MOEDAS **********/
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try{
        Coins coins = new HTTPService(arrayList)
                .execute()
                .get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class CoinsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Coins> {
//ATRIBUTOS
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Coins> arrayList;

public CoinsAdapter(@NonNull Context c, ArrayList<Coins> objects) {
    super(c, 0,objects);
    this.context = c;
    this.arrayList = objects;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    //VALIDANDO E CRIANDO A LISTA DE MOEDAS
    if (arrayList != null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //montando a view a partir do xml
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, parent, false);

        //RECUPERANDO OS COMPONENTES PARA EXIBICAO
        TextView tvRank = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_rank);
        TextView tvCoin = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_coin);
        TextView tvPreco = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_preco);
        TextView tvMarket = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_market);
        TextView tvVol = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_vol);
        TextView tv1hr = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_1h);
        TextView tv24hr = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_24h);
        TextView tv7d = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_7d);

        //GRAVANDO OS DADOS DE ACORDOD COM A CLASSE MODELO
        Coins coins = arrayList.get(position);
        tvRank.setText(coins.getRank());
        tvCoin.setText(coins.getName());
        tvPreco.setText(coins.getPrice_usd());
        tvMarket.setText(coins.getMarket_cap_usd());
        tvVol.setText(coins.getVolume_usd_24h());
        tv1hr.setText(coins.getPercent_change_1h());
        tv24hr.setText(coins.getPercent_change_24h());
        tv7d.setText(coins.getPercent_change_7d());

    }
    return view;
}
}
```

a classe que faz a requisição com o webservice:

```
public class HTTPService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Coins> {
//ATRIBUTOS
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;
private List<Coins>  lCoins;
private ArrayList<Coins> arrayList;

public HTTPService(ArrayList<Coins> coins) {
    this.arrayList = coins;

}


@Override
protected Coins doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        //URL QUE SERÁ CONSUMIDA
        URL url = new URL("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10");

        //---- ABRINDO A CONEXÃO ---
        HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexao.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conexao.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");
        conexao.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conexao.setDoOutput(true);
        conexao.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        conexao.connect();

        //----- LENDO AS INFORMAÇÕES -------
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        arrayList.clear();

        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            resposta.append(scanner.next());
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

            //CONVERTENDO O RETORNO PARA A CLASSE MODELO
    lCoins = new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Coins>>(){}.getType() );
    //arrayList.add((Coins) lCoins);

    return lCoins.size() > 0 ? lCoins.get(0) : null;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Coins coins) {
    super.onPostExecute(coins);

    for (int i = 0; i <= lCoins.size(); i++){
        arrayList.add(lCoins.get(i));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

}
```

Fiz algumas alterações e funciono, primeiro alterei o retorno usando o exemplo que você tinha me sugerido em um post anterior: `return lCoins.size() > 0 ? lCoins.get(0) : null;` em seguida coloquei o for para recuperar o resultado e listar linha a linha no onpostexecute e deu certo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Você **não** pode manipular a *UI* no método `doInBackground`. Para isso é necessário que você mova seu código responsável por exibir os dados para o usuário para o método `onPostExecute`.

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente, se quiser colocar como resposta o for dentro do onpostexecute pode colocar pois você merece pontos positivos por isso ! Obrigado !